# Is there a way to clean out old "Unanswered" questions that really are answered?

Tags: discussion, comments, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions

I've looked through related questions suggested on meta for this title, and I think this one is slightly different.  In this question, I'm asking about questions that really have been answered correctly, and the OP indicates such in a response, but doesn't complete the process.

I'm fairly new to SO, but I've already noticed a lot of cases where:

1) A question will be asked, usually by a new member.

2) An answer will be given, upvoted, and sometimes even "thanked" by the OP for resolving the problem.

3) The OP, probably because they are new and don't really "get" the rep system yet, wanders off and leaves it with no accepted answer.

4) It goes stagnant and lives in the "Unanswered" pile forever.

**Slight variant**:

2a) An answer that is helpful is actually given in the comments instead of as a direct answer, the OP leaves a comment saying thanks and that it is resolved.

3b) The OP doesn't know to ask the commenter to make it a formal answer so it can be accepted.

4) Same as above.

If there a way to make it clear to new members how to handle these situations?

Furthermore, is there a way to mark old questions like this with an accepted answer so they don't clog up the Unanswered "pile"?

Comment: Questions with an upvoted answer are not unanswered

Comment: I may be misunderstanding something then.  It seems they still show up under Unanswered unless one has been accepted and has the 'checkmark'.  I think it still applies to questions that have a valid answer in the comments section only, as well.

Comment: Ok, I missed that question.  Thanks.

Comment: Several years later, dozens of other users (including me) are still trying to debate this issue. I really hope SO staff will consider the idea eventually. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354584/534406